# Insect Identification Request - Is this a Satin Moth or something else?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

```
Date:     July 2, 2018  
Time:     11:00 AM
Location: Minneapolis MN  
Size:     Approx. 1" from head to tail
```

[image: Pure white moth]
I saw this moth at work today. I wasn't sure if it was just a Satin Moth, an albino (it *seems* to have some pigment), or something else. It fluttered over to the door and landed there to rest. A few minutes later it disappeared.

I would really appreciate some help identifying it. Please comment if I need to add additional information.